# Apache problems after upgrading to Yosemite

Tags: apache-http-server, httpd

My Mac web server won't work after upgrading to Yosemite. When I type `apachectl` into Terminal, I get this:

```
httpd: Syntax error on line 527 of /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 8 of /private/etc/apache2/other/+php-osx.conf: Cannot load /usr/local/php5/libphp5.so into server: dlopen(/usr/local/php5/libphp5.so, 10): Symbol not found: _unixd_config\n  Referenced from: /usr/local/php5/libphp5.so\n  Expected in: /usr/sbin/httpd\n in /usr/local/php5/libphp5.so
```

If I type `sudo apachectl [re]start` nothing happens, as if it's started and I type it again, it says it's already running. Also, I have the Web Sharing Preference pane installed  (http://clickontyler.com/web-sharing/) and when I flick the switch from Off to On, it still says it's off, even though the switch is at the On position.

What files do you guys want/need to see? Really need to fix this ASAP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please also note that the Yosemite installer overwrites the entire /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf file with the new default Apache 2.4 configuration file.

For example, if any `Listen` directives were added, they will have disappeared and need to be added again. E.g.:

```
Listen 127.0.0.1:81
```

I found my old configuration in the following file, but due to differences from 2.2, it should probably not be copied directly over the http.conf file:

/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf~previous

There is an upgrade guide at: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html

Make sure that any previously included extra config files are still included, and then test the configuration with the command:

```
sudo apachectl configtest
```

Comment: How does that answer the question? You shouldn't have to change what php module you're loading after upgrading Apache...

Answer (score 8):

The problem occurs because Yosemite installs the latest version of Apache (2.4) whereas earlier versions of Mac OS X used Apache version 2.2

From the error, it appears that you were not using the standard version of PHP provided by Apple but a different version supplied by liip.ch.  Removing the # sign as suggested by Nuttyx above will load the Apple version of php (5.5.14).  If you wish to continue running the version supplied by liip you will need to reinstall it so that it loads properly in Apache 2.4.  See a detailed explanation here: (http://blog.liip.ch/archive/2014/06/11/php-osx-available-for-os-x-10-10-yosemite.html)

N.B.  If you are using virtual hosts you will probably need to change your configuration files somewhat.  In particular you will need to change the following:

2.2 configuration:

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

2.4 configuration:

```
Require all granted
```

Answer (score 4):

It seems that you can fix this by **removing** the `#` at the beggining of the following line in `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` file:

```
LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

Comment: This did it for me !

Answer (score 1):

Running 'sudo apachectl' without arguments shows the problem in the conf files. In my case upgrading php did fixed it.

```
curl -s http://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 5.6
```

After that, Apache run again but I had to reconfigure the vhosts.

Answer (score 0):

While the above question has been answered, there is another possibility of the same error like:

```
/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf: Cannot load /usr/libexec/apache2/mod_XYZ.so into server: dlopen(/usr/libexec/apache2/mod_XYZ.so, 10): image not found
```

This could happen if you have created a symbolic link that is being referred in the name above and it is not found. To resolve create a symbolic link providing the absolute path for the actual file and the same for the symlink file name being provided.